# How can I implement external authentication to next.js?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I have a backend which is written in go language. I want to implement it's jwt token authentication to my Next.js app. But I couldn't find any useful information, I have checked next.js documentation, there is next-auth but I can not understand it's credentials logic and there is no enough resources or documentation to understand it.

Do you know any method for adding external API authentication to Next.js ?

Answer (score 0):

All next.js does is provide a node.js environment to run your server code which then spits out your frontend pages prebuilt on the server. You can pretty much do anything with this, meaning there are multiple solutions to using a separate backend, and you would need to provide more information on what you are trying to achieve.

A common way to implement a JWT token would be (as you already mentioned) next-auth, you can check [this guide](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/seamless-authentication-and-authorization-in-nextjs-leveraging-external-jwts-in-next-auth-1af1ef8fd7d8) for that.

The next.js and also the next-auth documentation is quite extensive, if you still think it doesn't provide the info you need I would recommend checking the [tutorials page](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials) of next-auth.

Especially

> [Add auth support to a Next.js app with a custom backend](https://arunoda.me/blog/add-auth-support-to-a-next-js-app-with-a-custom-backend)

might be of great value to you.

Comment: Example I can integrate it to my react app with context. But I use useEffect and states for it, in next.js hooks make it meaningless. I have checked medium guide before it shows implementation for page route. I am using next.js app route, in auth tutorial page. there is nothing about custom rest api implementation. I found some medium posts and all of them are just not cover this topic fully. I also tried to use httpOnly cookies but it can create CSRF vulnerability. 

http://localhost:9090/api/login <- that's my login. I want to send email and password as a data and get response from it.

Comment: It says custom backend, but just implement it with github provider :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use credentials provider from Auth.js to make a request to your custom/external backend API login endpoint, and store that response (including user data and for sure the JWT) into the session cookie of Auth.js.

Maybe you have to augment/extend the types from Auth.js, in order to add custom properties to JWT and Session Object like accesToken o userAddress, etc.

I recommend you to learn [this section](https://authjs.dev/getting-started/typescript) of Auth.js documentation to do that.

For subsequents requests from your nextjs enviroment you can append the 'Bearer token' header to retrieve data from your external backend.